# Photoshop CS6 scripting : extracting manual transformation info

Tags: scripting, photoshop

well, the title is quite self explanatory. I'm trying to extract, via a script in java, the information of a transformation I perform manually on a layer (Ctrl+T / Distort ) in Photoshop (in order to later apply it on other layers). Any idea on how to do that? or if that's doable at all.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried creating a macro (action) instead? Also do you mean java or javascript? You have javascript as a tag in  your question, but you mention java in the question.

Comment: I meant javascript, sorry for the misunderstanding.
I don't have a code per se, I currently use a custom loop script and an action. 
The problem with the action is that I have to redo the transformation manually for each layer (I cannot save it directly in the action since transformation is going to be different depending on the situation).

I'd like my script to memorize this custom transformation and apply it, so that I don't have to do it by hand for each layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an action that can be repeated on a layer. This can be accomplished via `Actions`. You just need to record that custom transformation and then apply that action a different layer. This will apply the same transformation again. Have a look at https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html